# Excel column limit

Tags: c#, excel

is excel's columns limited to 256 ? i try to fill my excel file with a matrix of 1200 x 800 and it doesn't seem to work ( i recieve an error that states that any data beyond the 256 column will not be saved ) . any ideas how this  could be avoided ?

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get around it.  Is multiple sheets not an option.

Comment: Why the close votes?  This is a legitimate question re a C# programming problem.

Comment: Maybe it depends on library you use?  I had similar problem...

Answer (score 7):

Older versions of Excel had a maximum of 256 columns. Excel 2007 increased the column limit to over 16000.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, limits on worksheet size are way more than that - see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx) for program constraints (Excel 2007). Your problem must be elsewhere (or in Excel version being older).

> 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to a higher version excel, you are using excel 2003 or earlier. [2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=1) and [2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx?CTT=1) offer more columns.